# How to get a python lookup to return another column after match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 lists, df and df2 (which is a taxonomy).  I want to search a column in df using values from df2, and return ANOTHER value from df2, after a match/or matches are found.  How do I do it?

My attempt is

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['a cat', 'grey puppy', 'red dog']})
df
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'BroadTerm':['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'], 'NarrowTerm':['cat', 'kitten', 'puppy', 'dog']})
```

```
NarrowTerm = df2.NarrowTerm.unique().tolist()
df['Animal'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: ','.join([part for part in NarrowTerm if part in x]))
df
```

which returns

```
    Name    Animal
0   a cat   cat
1   grey puppy  puppy
2   red dog dog
```

but I want it to return

```
    Name    Animal
0   a cat   cat
1   grey puppy  dog
2   red dog dog
```

**UPDATED DATA**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['a cat dog - multiple', 'grey puppy - narrow term', 'a cat puppy', 'reddog - single no spaces', 'acatdog - multiple no spaces']})
```

Comment: chain `.replace({'puppy':'dog'})` to your current method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done without `apply` using [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['Animal'] = df['Name'].str.extract(pat = f"({'|'.join(df2.NarrowTerm)})")[0].map(dict(df2.iloc[:,::-1].values))
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
         Name Animal
0       a cat    cat
1  grey puppy    dog
2     red dog    dog
```

*NOTE* : To create a mapping dict you can also use : `pd.Series(df2.BroadTerm.values,index=df2.NarrowTerm).to_dict()`

Answer (score 1):

You can split a string into a list of tokens in `df['Name']` and transform the `list` into `np.array`. Then, use `np.in1d()` to check if there is any token that exists in `df2['NarrowTerm']`. If true, return the corresponding `BroadTerm`.

Try this:

```
df['Animal'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: df2.loc[np.in1d(df2.NarrowTerm, np.array(x.split())), 'BroadTerm'].values[0])
```

Output:

```
print(df)

         Name  Animal
0       a cat    cat
1  grey puppy    dog
2     red dog    dog
```

Comment: Hi @Crystal - i got some errors when modifying the data set with some more test cases.

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0